# failure to resolve DNS query using IPv6, e.g. host -6 gnu.org, dig -6 gnu.org

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6, systemd-resolved

Why doesn't the default Ubuntu LTS install allow `host -6 gnu.org` or `dig -6 gnu.org` to work?

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-27-generic x86_64)

$ host -6 gnu.org
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused

$ dig -6 gnu.org
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
```

The stub resolver appears to listen only on IPv4:

```
$ tail -3 /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search home.idallen.ca

# netstat -nap | grep resolv
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      603/systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           603/systemd-resolve
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25992    603/systemd-resolve  /run/systemd/resolve/io.systemd.Resolve
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTED     25969    603/systemd-resolve
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25989    603/systemd-resolve
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     23439    603/systemd-resolve
```

How do I make Ubuntu LTS listen also on IPv6, and why isn't this the default?

**Details** (some IP addresses changed to protect the innocent):

I put my machine on my Cable ISP and it didn't work, even though I can `ping6` everywhere and `ssh -6` in and out.

I put my machine on my DSL ISP and it didn't work, even though I can `ping6` everywhere and `ssh -6` in and out.

**Details using my Cable ISP:**

```
$ ping -c 1 -4 gnu.org
PING gnu.org (209.51.188.116) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wildebeest1p.gnu.org (209.51.188.116): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=29.4 ms

$ ping -c 1 -6 gnu.org
PING gnu.org(wildebeest1p.gnu.org (2001:470:142:5::116)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from wildebeest1p.gnu.org (2001:470:142:5::116): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=28.5 ms

$ host -4 gnu.org
gnu.org has address 209.51.188.116
gnu.org has IPv6 address 2001:470:142:5::116
gnu.org mail is handled by 10 eggs.gnu.org.

$ tail -3 /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search phub.net.cable.rogers.com

$ resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s25)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 64.71.255.204
        DNS Servers: 64.71.255.204 64.71.255.198 2607:f798:18:10:0:640:7125:5204
                    2607:f798:18:10:0:640:7125:5198
                    2607:fea8:c2e0:86f0:494:35ff:fea4:dcba
        DNS Domain: phub.net.cable.rogers.com

$ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2607:fea8:c2e0:86f0::abcd dev enp0s25 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
2607:fea8:c2e0:86f0::/64 dev enp0s25 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s25 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::494:35ff:fea4:dcba dev enp0s25 proto ra metric 20100 pref medium

$ host -6 gnu.org
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
```

**Details using my DSL ISP (only the parts that differ from Cable):**

```
$ tail -3 /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search home.idallen.ca

$ resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s25)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 2607:f2c0::1
        DNS Servers: 192.168.2.254 2607:f2c0::1 2607:f2c0::2
        DNS Domain: home.idallen.ca

$ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2607:f2c0:f00e:5d00::/64 via fe80::3e90:66ff:fed4:acdb dev enp0s25 proto ra metric 100 pref high
fe80::/64 dev enp0s25 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::3e90:66ff:fed4:acdb dev enp0s25 proto ra metric 20100 pref low

$ host -6 gnu.org
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
```

Comment: It works for me. Do you have a valid IPv6 address? `ip a`

Comment: Yes, I have a valid IPv6 address.  See edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same issue these days and after a little research, I think this has nothing to do with your ISP neither your network config.

1. **Solution A**: Use `dig gnu.org AAAA` to get the IPv6 of it.
2. **Solution B**: Make `systemd-resolved` listen on `[::1]:53` by adding `DNSStubListenerExtra=[::1]:53` into `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, according to:

   - [Klaus answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/674094)
   - [man resolved.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/resolved.conf.html#DNSStubListenerExtra=)

Comment: Yes, **Solution B** works for `systemd` version 247 or greater; the answer is `DNSStubListenerExtra` in the man page for `resolved.conf` but it's not available for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  It will work for Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: I have two systems: The one with 22.04 works without having this setting (i.e. it works by default). But, for the 23.04 I need the setting described in **Solution B**. Why is this so?

Comment: Worth pointing out `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` doesn't support trailing comments on lines. So you can't have:
```
DNSStubListenerExtra=[::1]:53 # for XYZ
```
you'll need to put the comment on the line before instead.